# TypeScript infers a more general type at static implementation

Tags: typescript, oop, generics, constructor

I stumbled upon an odd situation in TypeScript with the following code:

```
function staticImplements<T>() {
    return (constructor: T) => {};
}

enum FruitList {
    APPLE,
    BANANA,
    PEAR,
}

interface FruitInterface {
    fruit: FruitList;
}

abstract class Fruit implements FruitInterface {
    fruit: FruitList;

    constructor(fruit: FruitList) {
        this.fruit = fruit;
    }
}

interface AppleConstructor {
    new(fruit: FruitList.APPLE): AppleInterface;
}

interface AppleInterface extends Fruit {
    fruit: FruitList.APPLE;
}

class Apple extends Fruit implements AppleInterface {
    fruit: FruitList.APPLE;

    constructor(fruit: FruitList) {
        super(fruit);
    }
}
staticImplements<AppleConstructor>()(Apple);
```

As you can see, the constructor of `Fruit` expects the parameter `fruit` of type `FruitList` and so does the constructor of the child class `Apple` however the field `fruit` of `AppleInterface` expects only the value `APPLE` of the enum `FruitList` instead of all possible values the enum holds like its parent `FruitInterface`. The same goes for `AppleConstructor` which expects the parameter `fruit` to be of type `FruitList.APPLE` which is being used to check if `Apple` static implements the interface with the function `staticImplements` at the last line. The thing is, TypeScript states it does however it does not, how can this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your basic problem is that the TypeScript type system is somewhat unsound (so you can write some non-type-safe code).  Soundness is [not a goal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) of TypeScript, although if this error is common they may be interested in addressing it if you open an [issue in GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues).  I couldn't find one for your exact problem.

The particular unsoundness here has to do with not enforcing [type variance](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1394).  In short, property *reads* of subtypes can be *covariant* (subclasses can narrow their read-only properties), but property *writes* can only be *contravariant* (subclasses should *widen* their write-only properties).  If a property is meant to be both read and written, it must be *invariant* to be sound.

TypeScript allows subclass properties to be *covariant*.  That means things generally work well when you read properties, but sometimes bad things can happen when you write them.

Let me restate the main problem here using less code:

```
interface A {
  x: string | number
}
interface B extends A {
  x: number
}
const b: B = {x: 0};
const a: A = b;
a.x = "whoops"; // no error
b.x; // number at compile time, but string at runtime
b.x.toFixed(); // works at compile time, error at runtime
```

See how `B` is considered a subtype of `A`, which is fine until you try to write the wrong thing to its property.  People tend not to do this, so the language maintainers have left it alone, since preventing this issue is difficult and really limiting (would you really like to have write-only properties?).

In your case, your subclass is calling the constructor method of the superclass to write a (wider) property, even though that property has supposedly been narrowed by the subclass.  This is the same issue.

---

So here's a possible way to address your particular issue: use generics to specify your actual constraints so that the narrowing/widening happens only where you expect it:

```
interface FruitInterface<T extends FruitList> {
  fruit: T;
}

abstract class Fruit<T extends FruitList = FruitList> implements FruitInterface<T> {
  fruit: T;

  constructor(fruit: T) {
      this.fruit = fruit;
  }
}

interface AppleConstructor {
  new(fruit: FruitList.APPLE): AppleInterface;
}

interface AppleInterface extends Fruit<FruitList.APPLE> {
}

class Apple extends Fruit<FruitList.APPLE> implements AppleInterface {
  constructor(fruit: FruitList) {
      super(fruit); // now error as you expect
  }
}
```

To fix the above error, you should change the constructor to only take a `FruitList.APPLE`.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Marked your answer as the solving answer as it also comes with a fix. Also the answer is more detailed. Thanks @jcalz!